# Positioning flex items

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container with three flex item children. I would like the first div to be positioned at the left(flex-start), the second would need to be centered horizontally and the third one should be at the very right(flex-end).

I tried with pretty much every combo possible, but no luck.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: #222;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #666;
  flex-basis: 50px;
  height: 60px;
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #fff;
  flex-basis: 150px;
  height: 60px;
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #eee;
  flex-basis: 80px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class></div>
  <div class></div>
  <div class></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center flex item between 2 flex items of different widths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287476/horizontally-center-flex-item-between-2-flex-items-of-different-widths)

Answer (score 1):

On `.container` you need set the `justify-content` property to `space-between`. This property defines the alignment along the main axis.

```
.container{
  justify-content: space-between; 
}
```

More info here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/

Comment: Yes, but if the third element(in my scenario) is wider than the first two, then the second element is not centered. Of course, it gravitates to the left now :(

Comment: I see what you mean now-- I will do some testing and see if its possible using flex.