# Horizontally center flex item between 2 flex items of different widths

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Say I have 3 divs displayed horizontally with `flexbox`:

```
 |     |-div1-| |-center-div-| |-wider-div-|     |
```

And I want the center div to be aligned to the middle of the parent.  How can I accomplish this? `justify-content` will center all 3 of the divs based the sum of all their widths, and applying `align-self: center` to the middle div does nothing because the align property manipulates positioning on the other axis.

Is there a responsive CSS solution, or should I resort to jQuery?

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
}
li {
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href = "#">short</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">want center</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">loooooooooooooooooong</a></li>
</ul>
```

Illustration of this problem: 
https://jsfiddle.net/7w8mp8Lj/2/

Comment: This shouldn't be marked duplicate. This is distinct from the one it's marked duplicate of. The solution on the other one will not work for this problem, but the solution @Sitckers  gave will work there.

Comment: Agreed. This is not a duplicate. The other question is broad. This question is specific. And the search engine found this question, not the other. If we can not search the net and find an answer, how is it helpful?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the first and last `li` to grow `flex: 1`, and set `a` as inline block and text align 1/2/3 `li` as right/center/left.

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nm9dywjx/)**

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: right;
    flex: 1;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
    text-align: left;
    flex: 1;
}
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">short</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">want center</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">loooooooooooooooooong</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a flex method that perfectly centers the middle item with:

- no jQuery
- no absolute positioning
- no changes to the HTML

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
li:first-child > a {
  margin-right: auto;
}
li:last-child > a {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">short</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">want center</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">loooooooooooooooooong</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gf19ofry/)

Here's how it works:

- The `ul` is the primary flex container.
- Each `li` flex item is given `flex: 1` for an equal distribution of container space.
- Now the `li`s are consuming all space in the row and are equal width.
- Make each `li` a flex container and add `justify-content: center`
- Now each anchor element is a centered flex item.
- Use flex `auto` margins to shift the outer anchors left and right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use absolute positioning to take the non-centered items out-of-flow, so that they won't affect the centering.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  position: relative;
}
li > a {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
li:first-child > a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
li:last-child > a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">short</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">want center</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">loooooooooooooooooong</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, note you will lose flexibility because absolutely-positioned children of a flex container do not participate in flex layout (except in the reordering step).

Answer (score 1):

I use a flex container with three boxes inside, two of which -- left and right -- have the same width and are flex containers themselves, wrapping the content of arbitrary width:

```
[(a box)        ]     [centered content]    [    (a longer box)]
  left wrapper                                 right wrapper
```

Here is the code:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="wrapper left">
        <div class="box one"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
    <div class="wrapper right">
        <div class="box three"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 33%;
    display: flex;
}

.wrapper.left {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.one {
    width: 100px;
}

.two {
    width: 50px;
}

.three {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. The width was the key for me!